# Tree node alignment wrong

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am having a mental block and I hope someone can help. I am trying to draw the following tree and have two problems:

1. The subtree that is rooted at the left-most "doc" should be rooted at node &o2. Don't know why it is coming up this way.
2. The edges should be directed.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily}},>=latex,align=center,font={\fontsize{10pt}{12}\selectfont}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
tree node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=0.5cm},
every child node/.style={tree node}]

\node[circle,draw] {\&o1}
child {node {\&o2} edge from parent node[midway] {doc}
    child {node {\&o3} edge from parent node[midway] {authors}}
    child {node {\&o6} edge from parent node[midway] {title}}
}
child {node {\&o22} edge from parent node[midway] {doc}}
child {node {\&o34} edge from parent node[midway] {doc}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Many thanks for the assistance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the nodes children of the doc node, and that's what you got. If you move the edge after the two kids, you get

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily}},>=latex,align=center,font={\fontsize{10pt}{12}\selectfont}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
tree node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=0.5cm},
every child node/.style={tree node},
every path/.append style={-latex}]

\node[circle,draw] {\&o1}
child {node {\&o2} 
    child {node {\&o3} edge from parent node[midway,above,sloped] {authors}} 
    child {node {\&o6} edge from parent node[midway,above,sloped] {title}} 
    edge from parent node[midway,above,sloped] {doc} }
child {node {\&o22} edge from parent node[midway,above,sloped] {doc}}
child {node {\&o34} edge from parent node[midway,above,sloped] {doc}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would recommend using `forest`, which is arguably much more intuitive.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{el/.style={edge label={node[above,pos=0.5,sloped,font=\sffamily]{#1}}}}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={circle,draw,l+=2em,s sep=5em,font=\sffamily,edge=-latex}
    [\&o1 
     [\&o2,el=doc
      [\&o3,el=authors]
      [\&o6,el=title]
     ]
     [\&o22,el=doc]
     [\&o34,el=doc]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, of course. Many thanks -- I missed the placement of the nodes. Thanks also for the suggestion to use forest. I need to learn it and this looks like a good time to do that.